# angularjs 1.x support lifecycle and end-of-life

Tags: angularjs, end-of-life

I am currently managing an AngularJS development project. There is talk that we need to move to at least AngularJS 1.5 from our current 1.2.  One of my requirements to move is that I have to provide evidence of the end of support for 1.5 but cannot find any end of support information after many hours on the angular site and multiple google searches.

Has there been an official comment on when security patches and bug fixes will no longer be developed for Angular v1.x?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

End Of Life for AngularJS is December 31st, 2021. You can read more about it [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status) on the AngularJS docs page.

Previously the EOL was scheduled for June 30, 2021. However, the Angular team [released a blog post](https://blog.angular.io/angularjs-lts-extended-in-response-to-covid-19-321b037212f5) stating that they moved that deadline back to the end of December 2021 due to COVID-19.

> On July 1st 2018, we entered a Long Term Support (LTS) period for AngularJS 1.8. We originally announced that we would discontinue the support on the 31st of July 2021.
>
> Over the past few months we heard that many companies are hurt by the unprecedented times caused by the global pandemic of COVID-19. In response, we are extending the AngularJS LTS with another 6 months, until the 31st of December 2021.

A lot of companies have yet to begin/finish their migrations away from AngularJS 1.x. On the AngularJS docs there is a project referenced called [XLTS.dev](https://angularjs.xlts.dev) that will be providing an extended support for AngularJS projects. That team is made up of some of the core AngularJS team members, AngularJS Material team members, inventors of Angular Universal, former Angular team members, the Scully team members, and ng-conf team members. Sounds like you can go there to continue getting:

- Security Patches
- Browser Breakage Patches
- jQuery Breakage Patches

This is great news for anyone still on an AngularJS project that needs support.

Comment: +1 for this
>There are far too many large applications written on top of Angular 1.x to just drop everything and dash off to Angular2

Comment: New Official update from Angularjs team: https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c .     From 1st July 2018, Angularjs team will only do security update until July 2021.

Comment: Alright now let's make thousands of bots to generate some traffic on angularjs.org :D that'll save our large applications...

Comment: Large costs involved here

Answer (score 19):

> Has there been an official comment on when security patches and bug fixes will no longer be developed for Angular v1.x?

Not until last contributor goes away! Foremost AngularJS is licensed under liberal [MIT License](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/LICENSE) and everybody can fork it and modify it endlessly.

For those worrying about "official Google support" - well, between March 2016 and March 2017 there were 20 releases of AngularJS 1.x - [the latest is 1.6.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) - doesn't look like abandoned project any time soon. It differs so much from Angular v2 and v4 (to be released this month) that it will have it's own life even after Google decides move away. Either they transfer the github project to community maintainers or community fork will take over.

There are [lots of spectacular examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_forks) of communities taking over projects for various reasons. A notable example is io.js - [large group of contributors decided to fork Node.js](http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/nodejs-iojs-why-the-fork/) when Joyent, the creator company, was not releasing updates often enough to satisfy the community.

This is the beauty of open source software.

Comment: Great answer! And even more amazing to see a Wiki for this. :D

Answer (score 16):

The AngularJS team announced the end of official support by July 2021. They will release one more version (v1.7) and in July 2018, they will enter a Long Term Support period of 3 years.

During this LTS period they will only apply fixes to v1.7 that are essential for security or browser compatibility, or jQuery changes that would cause production applications to stop working.

After the LTS period, no changes will be made anymore (by Google).

The official announcement can be found in the Angular Blog: [Stable AngularJS and Long Term Support](https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c).

Answer (score 9):

An update has been posted to the Angular blog on 2018-01-26: [Stable AngularJS and Long Term Support](https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c)

> The team is currently working towards a release of AngularJS 1.7.0 and we will continue development of 1.7 through June 30, 2018. On July 1, we will enter a 3 year period of Long Term Support (LTS).
>
> - January 1 — June 30, 2018 AngularJS 1.7 Active Development
> - July 1, 2018 — December 31, 2021 AngularJS 1.7 LTS Period

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the post to the Angular blog on 2018-01-26: [Stable AngularJS and Long Term Support](https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c)

The following announcement has been added to the AngularJS Docs:

> #### After July 1st 2018
>
> Any version branch not shown in the following table (e.g. 1.6.x) is no longer being developed.
>
> ```
> Version   Status  Comments
> 1.2.x   Long Term Support   Last version to provide IE 8 support
> 1.7.x   Long Term Support   See Long Term Support section below.
> ```
>
> ### Long Term Support
>
> On July 1st 2018, we will enter a Long Term Support period for AngularJS.
>
> At this time we will focus exclusively on providing fixes to bugs that satisfy at least one of the following criteria:
>
> - A security flaw is detected in the 1.7.x branch of the framework
> - One of the major browsers releases a version that will cause current production applications using AngularJS 1.7.x to stop working
> - The jQuery library releases a version that will cause current production applications using AngularJS 1.7.x to stop working.
>
> — [AngularJS MISC - Long Term Support](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status#after-july-1st-2018)

Answer (score 3):

Just to keep things here up to date, the LTS offered by Google was extended from mid 2021 to December 2021. Information for this can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status) which now includes information on how to get support beyond Google's provided LTS.